# XmlPath selecting a list of parent attributes based on a conditional child attribute into a List of Strings

Tags: java, rest-assured

Given the following XML:

```
<Holiday ItineraryId="123456789" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
   <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
      <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
   </Flight>
</Holiday>

<Holiday ItineraryId="9283873737" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
   <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
      <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
   </Flight>
</Holiday>

<Holiday ItineraryId="894847463" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
   <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
      <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
  </Flight>
</Holiday>

<Holiday ItineraryId="894847463" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
   <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="false">
      <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
  </Flight>
</Holiday>
```

How can I select *all* the itineraryID's into a List of Strings where the condition MultiLegOutboundFlight="true" is met?

I have tried:

```
allMultiLegPackages = response.xmlPath().getList("Holiday.Flight{it.@MultiLegOutboundFlight=='true'}//parent::Holiday");
```

...and this successfully returns a list of the Nodes that meet the condition. But how do I get the atttribute list of ItineraryId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this snippet will help you.

```
XmlPath xmlpath = new XmlPath(responseXML);
List<Node> holidayNodes = xmlpath.getList("Holidays.Holiday.findAll{it.Flight.@MultiLegOutboundFlight=='true'}");
List<String> itineraryList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Node node: holidayNodes){
itineraryList.add(node.getAttribute("ItineraryId"));
}
System.out.println(itineraryList);
```

It seems your XML response have multiple root nodes `Holiday`. I think we should have only one root node. Declare all Holiday nodes in one root node `Holidays`

Comment: The above code works perfectly if your XML format is like 
`<Holidays>
<Holiday> </Holiday> <Holiday> </Holiday> 
</Holidays>`

Comment: there is no 'getAttribute' method in package org.w3c.dom Node interface?  getAttributes will not accept a String

Comment: I tried using Element in place of Node and received the following error: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

io.restassured.path.xml.exception.XmlPathException: Failed to parse the XML document

Comment: Sorry, I was using wrong Node import :(  Let me re-try

Comment: you are a legend!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XmlPath expression works, I think you just need to add "/@ItineraryId" to the end of it...  So something like:

```
allMultiLegPackages =
response.xmlPath().getList("Holiday.Flight{it.@MultiLegOutboundFlight=='true'}//parent::Holiday/@ItineraryId");
```

Comment: I wanted it to be this simple, but this does not work. I have tried many variations.

Comment: Assuming you did have an outermost <Holidays> element around all your individual <Holiday> elements, this XPath returns just the ItineraryIds:
   `//Holiday/Flight[@MultiLegOutboundFlight='true']//parent::Holiday/@ItineraryId`
I test it at https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html